# No maps showing on MapActivity

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

I have downloaded the Google API and now have whats seems to be a standard issue of my map XML is just displaying a grey grip where Google maps should be displayed, as shown:

[image]

I have tried two API keys (by generating a new one) to no avail. I have added the internet permission and Google maps library in my manifest as shown:

Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainMap"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

API keys:

[image]

This is my map XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="AIzaSyBV_Zio-pysGWfjGo7dUpGvYRZ9PB3NQLc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am setting my project to Google API's version of the SDK and the same with my AVD.

When my app is loaded and my intent starts I am getting the error in my console of:

```
02-16 15:55:04.637: E/MapActivity(305): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Comment: Read [this](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-map-api-key.html) and generate api key [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup)

Comment: Shouldn't the XML permission be within the XML for the Application

Comment: These method that you have tried to do was depreciated in DEC,2012: Please read [this document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/).  And even if you use the new Google Maps API v2, you cannot deploy your app in the emulator: Refer to [this document](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: Please [refer to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15021200/1983061)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your manifest and layout file are ok.This problem usually occurs due to the key problem. By using SHA1 Certificate fingerprints i have got the same problem.So i have gone for MD5 Certificate fingerprints. Go to this site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/maps-api-signup and give your MD5 fingerprints and get the key. to get the MD5 fingerprints

1. Open your command prompt by typing cmd in your run. Start ⇒ Run ⇒
   type cmd
2. Go to jdk's bin directory by typing cd c:\path-to-jdk-dir\bin\

   In my case i typed cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\
3. Then type keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore
   "C:\Users\user-name\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v

   In my case i typed keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore   "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v
4. Then you will be asked for a password. default password is android.

Finally you will get the MD5 Fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Emulator with Android 2.3.3 and while searching for a solution I've found out that it's a known issue for emulators with this OS version. Just try another emulator with different version, it should work. Hope this helps.